# How to make QT application use native Windows cursors instead of qt specific?

Tags: qt5, qstyle, qcursor

In my application I want to have native Windows cursors icons instead of loaded/built from qt resources.

For example Qt::SplitVCursor/Qt::SplitHCursor which differs from standard Windows.

[image: Native and QT5 SplitHCursor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sources of `qwindowscursor.cpp`:

```
switch (cursorShape) {
case Qt::SplitVCursor:
    return createPixmapCursorFromData(systemCursorSize(), standardCursorSize(), 32, vsplit_bits, vsplitm_bits);
case Qt::SplitHCursor:
    return createPixmapCursorFromData(systemCursorSize(), standardCursorSize(), 32, hsplit_bits, hsplitm_bits);
case Qt::OpenHandCursor:
    return createPixmapCursorFromData(systemCursorSize(), standardCursorSize(), 16, openhand_bits, openhandm_bits);
case Qt::ClosedHandCursor:
    return createPixmapCursorFromData(systemCursorSize(), standardCursorSize(), 16, closedhand_bits, closedhandm_bits);
case Qt::DragCopyCursor:
    return QCursor(QPixmap(copyDragCursorXpmC), 0, 0);
case Qt::DragMoveCursor:
    return QCursor(QPixmap(moveDragCursorXpmC), 0, 0);
case Qt::DragLinkCursor:
    return QCursor(QPixmap(linkDragCursorXpmC), 0, 0);
}
```

and then

```
// Non-standard Windows cursors are created from bitmaps
static const uchar vsplit_bits[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x03, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x03, 0x00,
    0x00, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Looks like Qt uses it's own bitmap for V/HSplit cursors. So the short answer is "impossible". The long answer is you have to modify the mentioned lines and recompile Qt. I doubt though that you can get the cursor you've mentioned from windows as it seems non-standard and the bitmap in Qt is there for a reason. Good luck, commit if you make it :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can modify the bitmap itself and recompile Qt - fast and dirty.

Comment: May I suggest to [open a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/) as well? It's the kind of thing that it's best fixed upstream. (Moreover, I wonder which `IDC_*` macro those cursors correspond to...)

Comment: Looks like you are right. I thought there is way without modifying QT.